# Exercise on vector subspace with norm

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is if the set $U=\left \{ x=\left ( x_{1},x_{2} \right ) \in \mathbb{R}^{2};\left \| x \right \|=\left |x _{1} \right |+\left | x_{2} \right |\right \}$ is a subspace of the vectorial space $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Let $u=\left ( x_{1},x_{2} \right ); \left | x_{1} \right |+\left | x_{2} \right |$ and $v=\left ( y_{1},y_{2} \right ); \left | y_{1} \right |+\left | y_{2} \right |$ two elements of $U$. Then

$u+v=\left ( x_{1}+y_{1},x_{2}+y_{2} \right )$ and $\alpha u=\left ( \alpha x_{1},\alpha x_{2} \right )$

My problem is in the use of the norm to vectors $u+v$ and $\alpha u$, clear if you use the norm of addition the problem is solved.

Specifically how to demonstrate if the set $U$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Thank you for your help

Comment: It depends on what you mean by $\|x\|$. If you meant the Euclidean norm then $U$ is the axes.

Comment: If it is what @copper.hat says, note that you're not closed under addition, so it can't be a subspace (adding a unit vector in the direction the horizontal and vertical axis gives a non-axis vector).